# Problem with combine docx files with python docx

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I have several documents in docx format. They are created as docxtpl templates. I want to merge them into one final file. If condition 1 is fulfilled, then one document is selected. If condition 2 is fulfilled, then another document is selected.

I tried to use this method, but the document is incorrect. The document does not open and displays a message about incorrect content

```
import os
import docxtpl
from docx import Document


if __name__ == '__main__':
    docs_dir = "Some/way/to/docx-files"
    result_doc = docxtpl.Template(os.path.join(docs_dir), "result_doc.docx")

    if condition1:
        merged_doc = Document(os.path.join(docs_dir), "First_var.docx")
    else:
        merged_doc = Document(os.path.join(docs_dir), "Second_var.docx")

    for elem in merged_doc.element.body:
        result_doc.docx.element.body.append(elem)
```

A search using Google led to similar code, but the results remained the same. Has anyone encountered similar problems?

Comment: Upd: Maybe there is a way to remove pages from the resulting docx file?

Comment: I have never worked with docxtpl but I have used docx-compose for merging different documents together. Maybe this would help https://stackoverflow.com/a/54735397/11075199