# how can i merge a document containing hyperlinks .docx to an other .docx using python?

Tags: python, python-docx

I found this solution
[combine word document using python docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872527/combine-word-document-using-python-docx#comment88669331_29266278)
and someone said :

> If you just need to combine simple documents with only text, you can
> use python-docx as mentioned above.

If you need to merge documents containing hyperlinks, images, lists, bullet points etc. You can do this using lxml to combine the document body and all the reference files, like:

word/styles.xml
word/numbering.xml
word/media
[Content_Types].xml"
If he ever saw this I hope he can elaborate a little bit more
anyhow I want to merge a .docx to another .docx, a simple merge adding the content of the word document to the last page of the other document, the document could contain text, images, tables... all the hyperlinks that you can imagine, just grab the content of a document and put it into another, but I can't find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try docxcompose.

https://pypi.org/project/docxcompose/

This code creates a master document which adds doc1.

```
from docxcompose.composer import Composer
from docx import Document
master = Document("master.docx")
composer = Composer(master)
doc1 = Document("doc1.docx")
composer.append(doc1)
composer.save("combined.docx")
```

For example, if you also want to add doc2, you can add this after the sixth line:

```
doc2 = Document("doc2.docx")
composer.append(doc2)
```

Comment: thank you i'll try it today, but i want to know if there's a way that we can specify the path where "combined.docx" will be saved?

Comment: @trilogy0fg perhaps composer.save("C:/Users/yourname/Desktop/combined.docx")