# Concatenation two files in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following functions to read files, then store them inside variables:

```
def browseFiles():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/home",
                                          title = "Select a File",
                                          filetypes = (("Text files",
                                                        "*.docx*"),
                                                       ("all files",
                                                        "*.*")))
    label_file_explorer.configure(text="File Opened: "+ filename)
    with open(filename) as fp:
     firstfile = fp.read()

def browseFiles1():
    filename1 = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/home",
                                          title = "Select a File",
                                          filetypes = (("Text files",
                                                        "*.docx*"),
                                                       ("all files",
                                                        "*.*")))
    label_file_explorer.configure(text="File Opened: "+ filename1)
    with open(filename1) as fp:
     secondfile = fp.read()
```

I want to concatenate firstfile and secondfile together, then produce a third file. So, I used :

```
firstfile += "\n"
firstfile += secondfile
  
with open ('thirdfile.docx', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(firstfile)
```

My questions is how to access the variables firstfile and secondfile in each function and use them to produce a third file ?

Comment: It is better to open the file in binary mode if it is a `.docx` file.  But note that merging two `.docx` files is not the same as merging two text files.

Comment: Good point. Any link to opening a file in a binary mode would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the `firstfile` and the `secondfile` from the 2 functions, store them in variables and then use the `pd.concat` function.

```
def browseFiles():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/home",
                                          title = "Select a File",
                                          filetypes = (("Text files",
                                                        "*.docx*"),
                                                       ("all files",
                                                        "*.*")))
    label_file_explorer.configure(text="File Opened: "+ filename)
    with open(filename) as fp:
     firstfile = fp.read()

    return firstfile


def browseFiles1():
    filename1 = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/home",
                                          title = "Select a File",
                                          filetypes = (("Text files",
                                                        "*.docx*"),
                                                       ("all files",
                                                        "*.*")))
    label_file_explorer.configure(text="File Opened: "+ filename1)
    with open(filename1) as fp:
     secondfile = fp.read()
    
    return secondfile

firstfile = browseFiles()
secondfile = browseFiles1()

thirdfile = pd.concat([firstfile, secondfile])
```

Here is the [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to the documentation of concat.

Cheers!

Comment: So your solution to accessing two variables involves installing a 3rd party library?

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria What do you think would be the right solution ?

Comment: @Yahyaotaif Global variables seems like a solution, but I'm not sure what the OP wants

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria that would be my last resort.

Comment: lowkey, I get an error at this line thirdfile = pd.concat([firstfile, secondfile]) where firstfile and secondfile are not regonized.

Comment: @Yahyaotaif I dont know why you want to add all the files together

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria it is a mini project I'm working on for my employer where we receive multiple docx files from different sources and we need to have them in one file for ease of use.

Comment: @Yahyaotaif If you are trying to combine two files, are you sure the right way to combine it is like this?

Comment: I don't know any other way in python.

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria I found a library in python that does the merging, it is called docxcompose.

Comment: @Yahyaotaif What kind of error is it?

Comment: @Iowkey name 'firstfile' is not defined

Comment: @Yahyaotaif I have edited the code. It will work now

Comment: Typo: `BrowseFile1()` should be ` browseFile1()` instead.  BTW, can `pd.concat()` merge two `.docx` files actually?

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks bud! AFAIK concat is only for dataframes. For Word files there is another library. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872527/combine-word-document-using-python-docx this might help

Answer (score 0):

You can `return` the file contents from the two functions, and that's how you'll access both from your "main function".

Comment: Thats prolly not possible assuming the functions are callbacks triggered by a button, and `return` inside callbacks are quite useless