# Copy the entire word document and paste it at the end of another one and KEEP THE FORMAT with python

Tags: python, format, copy-paste, docx

I am going to put the function in a FOR loop so I can generate the receipt file like madly.

```
from docx import Document

def paste_TEMP(dest_doc):
    # open TEMP.docx and destination file
    temp_doc = Document('TEMP.docx')
    destination_doc = Document(dest_doc)

    # copy and paste TEMP.docx parapraph
    for paragraph in temp_doc.paragraphs:
        # create new paragraph
        new_paragraph = destination_doc.add_paragraph(paragraph.text)

        # copy format
        new_paragraph.style = paragraph.style

        # copy runs in paragraph
        for run in paragraph.runs:
            new_run = new_paragraph.runs[-1]  # 新段落的最後一個 run

            # copy run formats
            new_run.bold = run.bold
            new_run.italic = run.italic
            new_run.underline = run.underline
            new_run.font.name = run.font.name
            new_run.font.size = run.font.size
            

    # save files
    destination_doc.save(dest_doc)
    print(f"已將 TEMP.docx 的內容（包含格式）添加到 {dest_doc} 的最後面")

# example
paste_TEMP('YOUR_DESTINATION_FILE.docx')
```

The sameple file looks like this
[image]

But the copied file loses the formats
[image]

I'm not really familiar with word documents in Python. As you can see it was written by ChatGPT

I want to see the file pasted over and over the right format. If it can always be controlled within a page, it'll be great. However that might not be necessary

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872527/combine-word-document-using-python-docx

Comment: They don't fit my requirements. The formats are lost when the files are combined